# Create Multiple row from single row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data from 1 table with single row data
link : https://www.dropbox.com/s/86j2o9jo9v8vqip/stack1.PNG?dl=0

```
Function    dateMarine      NumberMarine    dateBOC         NumberBOC   Status
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Shipping    2000/01/01      10              2007/01/01      11          Paid
```

And I want to create multiple row from single row data 1 shipmentNumber , like this

```
Function    No.Doc  date        status 
--------------------------------------
Shipping   10       2000/01/01  Paid
Shipping   11       2007/01/01  Paid
```

How to create query for this case, I have some reference like this:

```
SELECT [Date]
      , API
      , LEFT(col,CHARINDEX('_',col)-1)'Latency'
      , RIGHT(col,CHARINDEX('_',REVERSE(col))-1)'Aggregation'
      , Value
FROM
(
  SELECT [Date],API,col,value
  FROM Table1
  CROSS APPLY
  (
    VALUES ('Latency1_Avg', [Latency1_Avg]),('Latency1_Min', [Latency1_Min]),('Latency1_Max', [Latency1_Max]),('Latency2_Avg', [Latency2_Avg]),('Latency2_Min', [Latency2_Min]),('Latency2_Max', [Latency2_Max])
  ) C (COL, VALUE)
) SRC
```

But i think my case is different

sorry i use the link to show picture of my case, because i cant import pic in my stackoverflow account

Thankyou for youre helping me

Comment: Plz type to text your sample data and expected result, not using image. And add your RDBMS tag, too

Comment: 1). You removed all image links. 2). Don't post images. Post formatted textual data

Comment: The reference you're using for the unpivot has the right idea, but you need to apply it differently. e.g. `select T.functionname, C.memodoc, C.memodate FROM mytable AS T CROSS APPLY (VALUES (memonumbermarien, memodatemarien), (memonumberboc, memodateboc), (memonumbercpi, memodatecpi)) AS C(memodoc, memodate);`

Comment: thankyou @ZLK, that's right